# Unable to resolve hostname(even after adding INTERNET permission)

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have been trying to run an application that stores and retrieves data from MySQL using PHP and Android. The whole project is on [this](http://androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) link.

I am getting the following error

```
05-01 20:38:57.833: W/System.err(28816): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.34 refused
05-01 20:38:57.842: W/System.err(28816):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:188)
05-01 20:38:57.842: W/System.err(28816):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
05-01 20:38:57.842: W/System.err(28816):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
05-01 20:38:57.842: W/System.err(28816):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
05-01 20:38:57.842: W/System.err(28816):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
05-01 20:38:57.842: W/System.err(28816):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
05-01 20:38:57.842: W/System.err(28816):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
05-01 20:38:57.842: W/System.err(28816):    at com.example.androidhive.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
05-01 20:38:57.842: W/System.err(28816):    at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:127)
05-01 20:38:57.842: W/System.err(28816):    at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
05-01 20:38:57.842: W/System.err(28816):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
05-01 20:38:57.842: W/System.err(28816):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-01 20:38:57.842: W/System.err(28816):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-01 20:38:57.843: W/System.err(28816):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-01 20:38:57.843: W/System.err(28816):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-01 20:38:57.853: W/System.err(28816): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.34 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
05-01 20:38:57.872: W/System.err(28816):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
05-01 20:38:57.872: W/System.err(28816):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
05-01 20:38:57.872: W/System.err(28816):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
05-01 20:38:57.872: W/System.err(28816):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
05-01 20:38:57.872: W/System.err(28816):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:124)
05-01 20:38:57.872: W/System.err(28816):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:149)
05-01 20:38:57.872: W/System.err(28816):    ... 14 more
05-01 20:38:57.873: W/System.err(28816): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
05-01 20:38:57.873: W/System.err(28816):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
05-01 20:38:57.873: W/System.err(28816):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
05-01 20:38:57.873: W/System.err(28816):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
05-01 20:38:57.873: W/System.err(28816):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
05-01 20:38:57.873: W/System.err(28816):    ... 19 more
05-01 20:38:57.874: E/Buffer Error(28816): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
05-01 20:38:57.897: E/JSON Parser(28816): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816): Process: com.example.androidhive, PID: 28816
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:130)
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-01 20:38:57.928: E/AndroidRuntime(28816):    ... 3 more
```

I have connected both my phone and the server(laptop-localhost) to the wifi. I have checked the ping after checking the ipconfig to know the ip address of localhost.

Ip address is 192.168.1.34 (obtained from ipconfig)

,ping is working fine using this ip address

this IP address is working in browser (displaying the local host when i type this ip address)

I have searched a lot and got the same answer to include foll. in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

But I had already included it and still facing the same problem.
Here is my code of manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidhive"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >


        <activity
            android:name=".MainScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- All Product Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".AllProductsActivity"
            android:label="All Products" >
        </activity>

        <!-- Add Product Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".NewProductActivity"
            android:label="Add New Product" >
        </activity>

        <!-- Edit Product Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".EditProductActivity"
            android:label="Edit Product" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!--  Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

Please help and oblige
Thank You

Comment: After adding 'http://localhost/android_connect/get_all_products.php' to browser,  I am getting the following output,"   {"pid":"1","name":"Siddharth","price":"1876.00","description":"sdkvjsdij","created_at":"2015-05-01 19:51:57","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}],"success":1}    " hence i think that the output is correct(so must be some problem with the N/W).

Comment: show your AsyncTask class. Are you using a framework or just normal php?

Comment: try using http://127.0.0.1/android_connect/get_all_products.php

Comment: The issue resolved now, I had turned the firewall ON. I had to turn it off. Thank You James for helping (y)

Comment: Hi James, Please help i have another problem, stuck in it for a long time now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018667/rsa-in-android-producing-right-keys-but-wrong-decryption

Answer (score 0):

use `192.168.1.34:80`. Let me know if it works. It worked for me.
If doesn't then follow this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

Comment: The issue is resolved, I had to turn the firewall off. Thank You Roon (y)

Comment: @SiddharthVerma Welcome Bhai.

Comment: Hi Roon13, please help i have come up with another problem :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018667/rsa-in-android-producing-right-keys-but-wrong-decryption

Answer (score 0):

Silly Me. I had turned the Firewall ON. Had to turn it off to make it work.

Thank You Every1 for help