# RSA in android producing right keys but wrong decryption

Tags: php, android, mysql, encryption, rsa

I am trying to encrypt username and password data in MySQL database using PHP and Android. I am keeping the data as a **BLOB** type in MySQL DB along with the **public key in the Database**.
NOTE : Retrieval and Submission of done is done in **JSON format using HTTP**.

**But** : I am getting the **wrong data**(**easily visible in log below** that (sid,a) is used for (username,password) and (YzJsawo=,YzJsawo=) is obtained) after decryption despite using Base64encoding to retrieve the data.(I have already tried it with CHAR and VARCHAR but no success).

**Please help** I have my project submission tomorrow. Worried. If at all u think that u won't be able to read the code that i have written please provide me with an alternative for above problem or a link where similar problem is discussed(Although i couldn't find one).

Here is what I am trying to do.

**Encryption Part**

```js
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
   
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     userStr = inputUsername.getText().toString();
     passStr = inputPassword.getText().toString();
     confirmpass = inputConfirmPass.getText().toString();
     
     if(userStr.equals("") || passStr.equals("") || confirmpass.equals(""))
     {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter all the fields" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
     else
     {
      if(passStr.equals(confirmpass))
      {
       //Encoding the string using RSA Algorithm
       
          // Original text
       valid=1;
       
          // Generate key pair for 1024-bit RSA encryption and decryption
          Key publicKey = null;
          Key privateKey = null;
          String publicKeyStr;
          try {
              KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
              kpg.initialize(1024);
              KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
              publicKey = kp.getPublic();
              privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("", "RSA key pair error");
          }
  
          byte[] encodedUser = null,encodedPassword = null;
          
          //Changing public key to str to transfer it between activities
          publicKeyStr = Base64.encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
  
          try {
              //Encoding Username
           // Encode the original data with RSA private key
           Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
              c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
              encodedUser = c.doFinal(Base64.encode(userStr.getBytes("utf-8"),Base64.DEFAULT));
              
              //Encoding Password
              encodedPassword = c.doFinal(Base64.encode(passStr.getBytes("utf-8"),Base64.DEFAULT));
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("Error Type:", "RSA encryption error");
          }
          
       String UsernameStrEncod,PasswordStrEncod;
          UsernameStrEncod = Base64.encodeToString(encodedUser, Base64.DEFAULT);
          PasswordStrEncod = Base64.encodeToString(encodedPassword, Base64.DEFAULT);
          
          
          List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", UsernameStrEncod));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", PasswordStrEncod));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("publickey", publicKeyStr));
       // getting JSON Object
       // Note that create product url accepts POST method
       JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_register_user,"POST", params);
       
       // check log cat fro response
       Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
    
       // check for success tag
       try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
    
        if (success == 1) {
         // successfully created product
         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
         //i.putExtra("encodedUser", encodedUser);
         //i.putExtra("publicKey", publicKeyStr);
         startActivity(i);
         
         // closing this screen
         finish();
        } else {
         // failed to create product
        }
       } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
      else
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Both the passwords do not match" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    }
   }); 
   return null;
  }
```

**Decryption Part**

```js
protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
  {

   // updating UI from Background Thread
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     // Check for success tag
     int success;
     int found=0;
     try {
      
      //EditText variable initialization
      inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UsernameID);
      inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordID);
      
      //Converting EditText to string 
      user = inputUsername.getText().toString();
      password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
      
      if(user.equals("") || (password.equals("")))
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter Both the fields" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
      // Building Parameters
      else
      {
       List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
       Log.d(user,password);
       // getting product details by making HTTP request
       // Note that product details url will use GET request
       JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login_details, "GET", params);
 
       // check your log for json response
       Log.d("Login Details", json.toString());
       
       // json success tag
       success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
       if (success == 1) 
       {
        // successfully received product details
        JSONArray userArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER); // JSON Array
        for(int j=0; (j<userArray.length()) && (found==0); ++j)
        {
          // get first product object from JSON Array
          JSONObject userObj = userArray.getJSONObject(j);
          String u = userObj.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
          String p = userObj.getString(TAG_PASSWORD);
          String publicKey = userObj.getString(TAG_PUBLICKEY);
          
          Log.d("usernameBlob:", u);
          Log.d("passwordBlob:", p);
          Log.d("publickeyBlob:", publicKey);
          
          //Decoding the data obtained from DB
          byte[] UsernameByteDecod = null, PasswordByteDecod = null;
          String UsernameStrDecod = null,PasswordStrDecod = null;
             try {
              //Converting the string public key into key type
              byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(publicKey.getBytes("utf-8"),Base64.DEFAULT);
              X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
              KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
              PublicKey publickey = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
              
              
              
                 Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
                 c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publickey);
              
                 //Decoding the data
                 UsernameByteDecod = c.doFinal(Base64.decode(u.getBytes("UTF-8"),Base64.DEFAULT));
                 PasswordByteDecod = c.doFinal(Base64.decode(u.getBytes("UTF-8"),Base64.DEFAULT));
                 UsernameStrDecod = Base64.encodeToString(UsernameByteDecod, Base64.DEFAULT);
              PasswordStrDecod = Base64.encodeToString(PasswordByteDecod, Base64.DEFAULT);
              
              Log.d("Username:",UsernameStrDecod);
              Log.d("Password:",PasswordStrDecod);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 Log.e("RSA Error:", "RSA decryption error");
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
          if((user.equals(UsernameStrDecod)) && (password.equals(PasswordStrDecod)))
          {
           found=1;
          }
          else if(user.equals(u))
          {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password is Incorrect" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           break;
          }
          else
          {
           
          }
          // display product data in EditText
        }
       }
       else
       {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You are not registered, Register Here" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        
        
       }
       if(found==1)
       {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome "+ user ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        
        //finish();

       }
       else if(found==0)
       {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You are not registered, Register Here" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        
        //finish();
       }
      }
     } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   });

   return null;
  }
```

**PHP Script for Inserting data after Encryption**

```js
<?php
 
/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */
 
// array for JSON response
$response = array();
 
// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['publickey']))
 {
 
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $publickey = $_POST['publickey'];
 
    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/users_db_connect.php';
 
    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
 
    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(username, password, publickey) VALUES('$username', '$password', '$publickey')");
 
    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Successfull Registration.";
 
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
 
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
 
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**PHP Script for retrieving data and Decrypting it afterwards**

```js
<?php
 
/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 *
 */
 
// array for JSON response
$response = array();
 
// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/users_db_connect.php';
 
// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
 
// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user") or die(mysql_error());
 
// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["user"] = array();
 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["username"] = $row["username"];
        $product["password"] = $row["password"];
        $product["publickey"] = $row["publickey"];
 
        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["user"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;
 
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No user found";
 
    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**Logcat**

```js
05-03 23:58:53.584: D/sid(26226): a
05-03 23:58:53.640: D/Login Details(26226): {"user":[{"username":"oBYxmonY0wmJhVbCZ69S\/OJYiVt7socheDmRfJM1vUyw1ACBA9ZraePdFJsvbYSjce\/UhxemRE+x\nRyF4d2GYLxfw+s0sw6Xo0P7T5bJ2gDqw7Grn+aAolhS4xzPnZm\/tytTVHVgyqdx\/UbWn8txu8h5D\nVj8WmLa0IstgcmvHRtQ=\n","password":"j\/iLoIjK5a1vJulTE4Hv7ofMQF48krK3xiDiBwGOJBsK7eGGnRskwjV+xUyT+jT3IeWQHbLncdWD\neG9HrQKiM2kE+t5SQ6CkCXVTcfWg8\/axmQC+UQt\/Q3s81UC64AMVBB0J0\/cZrdGeAQ8bGGVDkwC2\nf9WTl8RoAiMmpl6Q7gs=\n","publickey":"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCxZzks60BsVN6D\/2wJhXrURkzuDvljjEcN3hW6\n4JbjxK4UJb5T0uVtzULvyfceHcySlhqo2AcP0s+EybPuaZ+dwI1Mhd7VYg1Xeyz5EvLStAOreY3G\n3yweb4sryGvcty88Q4XkC\/KrcURGAT8QBzNVSc9cHJa+qPf1\/t+Eb9Yb3wIDAQAB\n"},{"username":"YjvJ6eNMNtU649ZgordslPURCNOt8ZgfkAm5WzNzlxxYZiYldAIg3PeOHjiOUsIunZuLlQ7\/uJG2\n9GBCTRDbQJeqOJ\/YaFePEjuydEHyN7CAay4ocUklVQkTdgSLkTEtU+RFifqGs3fM67fyQD3w8xq6\nyHb3vZMdJ3AS8cFS0fM=\n","password":"fr+vrqHzYBgvuHAnaRpNb+V9I0hn9crCuHNabF0v\/8PAY3a11fnE9v924sUTcgh4BDJVSzp\/sSxQ\nL1i7noh45buKPrZEz6BfGgiGqpwbjXTLKIyuNFjIyA3qbBFs9rxhYS00AsKmKO+zoB5AZ+I4amQQ\nwa3QKC\/wtHjPtV7BfwY=\n","publickey":"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDG9gggL32xWWArvV2FClklGPGUZPpsHUavy+l7\nGME2RwuI+nlARq9dM4TGyAY2A6APTj\/lD6\/uVfmvFvuo1MC2OSGBNNYNngoJ+J1Bg9kjwJUEktEF\nsO2L0iCTu0EQM+1SXlWe20k2sp4UmKdP0Rx3L8NqhbJLLoPLfA5qhCwNDQIDAQAB\n"}],"success":1}
05-03 23:58:53.640: D/usernameBlob:(26226): oBYxmonY0wmJhVbCZ69S/OJYiVt7socheDmRfJM1vUyw1ACBA9ZraePdFJsvbYSjce/UhxemRE+x
05-03 23:58:53.640: D/usernameBlob:(26226): RyF4d2GYLxfw+s0sw6Xo0P7T5bJ2gDqw7Grn+aAolhS4xzPnZm/tytTVHVgyqdx/UbWn8txu8h5D
05-03 23:58:53.640: D/usernameBlob:(26226): Vj8WmLa0IstgcmvHRtQ=
05-03 23:58:53.640: D/passwordBlob:(26226): j/iLoIjK5a1vJulTE4Hv7ofMQF48krK3xiDiBwGOJBsK7eGGnRskwjV+xUyT+jT3IeWQHbLncdWD
05-03 23:58:53.640: D/passwordBlob:(26226): eG9HrQKiM2kE+t5SQ6CkCXVTcfWg8/axmQC+UQt/Q3s81UC64AMVBB0J0/cZrdGeAQ8bGGVDkwC2
05-03 23:58:53.640: D/passwordBlob:(26226): f9WTl8RoAiMmpl6Q7gs=
05-03 23:58:53.640: D/publickeyBlob:(26226): MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCxZzks60BsVN6D/2wJhXrURkzuDvljjEcN3hW6
05-03 23:58:53.640: D/publickeyBlob:(26226): 4JbjxK4UJb5T0uVtzULvyfceHcySlhqo2AcP0s+EybPuaZ+dwI1Mhd7VYg1Xeyz5EvLStAOreY3G
05-03 23:58:53.640: D/publickeyBlob:(26226): 3yweb4sryGvcty88Q4XkC/KrcURGAT8QBzNVSc9cHJa+qPf1/t+Eb9Yb3wIDAQAB
05-03 23:58:53.641: D/Username:(26226): YzJsawo=
05-03 23:58:53.641: D/Password:(26226): YzJsawo=
05-03 23:58:53.641: D/usernameBlob:(26226): YjvJ6eNMNtU649ZgordslPURCNOt8ZgfkAm5WzNzlxxYZiYldAIg3PeOHjiOUsIunZuLlQ7/uJG2
05-03 23:58:53.641: D/usernameBlob:(26226): 9GBCTRDbQJeqOJ/YaFePEjuydEHyN7CAay4ocUklVQkTdgSLkTEtU+RFifqGs3fM67fyQD3w8xq6
05-03 23:58:53.641: D/usernameBlob:(26226): yHb3vZMdJ3AS8cFS0fM=
05-03 23:58:53.641: D/passwordBlob:(26226): fr+vrqHzYBgvuHAnaRpNb+V9I0hn9crCuHNabF0v/8PAY3a11fnE9v924sUTcgh4BDJVSzp/sSxQ
05-03 23:58:53.641: D/passwordBlob:(26226): L1i7noh45buKPrZEz6BfGgiGqpwbjXTLKIyuNFjIyA3qbBFs9rxhYS00AsKmKO+zoB5AZ+I4amQQ
05-03 23:58:53.641: D/passwordBlob:(26226): wa3QKC/wtHjPtV7BfwY=
05-03 23:58:53.641: D/publickeyBlob:(26226): MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDG9gggL32xWWArvV2FClklGPGUZPpsHUavy+l7
05-03 23:58:53.641: D/publickeyBlob:(26226): GME2RwuI+nlARq9dM4TGyAY2A6APTj/lD6/uVfmvFvuo1MC2OSGBNNYNngoJ+J1Bg9kjwJUEktEF
05-03 23:58:53.641: D/publickeyBlob:(26226): sO2L0iCTu0EQM+1SXlWe20k2sp4UmKdP0Rx3L8NqhbJLLoPLfA5qhCwNDQIDAQAB
05-03 23:58:53.647: D/Username:(26226): YzJsawo=
05-03 23:58:53.647: D/Password:(26226): YzJsawo=
```

Comment: To make things easy for you.....encrypt the password on the php  before saving it

Comment: I don't know how to do that @JamesNjuguna . Please provide me with a link for the same.

Comment: To make things easy for you.....encrypt the password on the php  before saving it...use the cypt function example..<?php $hashed = crypt("james"); echo $hashed; ?> it gives you an output of $1$LQRPfo2N$A35m/iDPcpOp0y4fhnxLf.

Comment: the code I have given you allows you to encrypt the password and you can check the password during login using the code on the if control structure

Comment: look at this http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this

```
          <?php
             $hashedpassword = crypt("james");

             /*echo $hashedpassword;
            */
           if (password_verify('james', $hashedpassword)) {
              echo 'Password is valid!';
           } else {
              echo 'Invalid password.';
           }
        ?>
```

Comment: anytime @SiddharthVerma.